# Proof of the second property of metrics for metric space $(C^{\infty}[a,b],\rho)$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $C^{\infty}[a,b] $ the set of all infinitely differentiable functions on $ [a, b] $, and let for $x,y \in  C^{\infty}[a,b]$,

$$ \rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot  \frac{\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|}{1+\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|  }$$

Is my proof of the property  of metrics 
if $\rho(x,y)=0$, then $x= y$
correct?

Proof:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot  \frac{\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|}{1+\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|  }    = 0$$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^k}\cdot  \frac{\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|}{1+\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|  }    = 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle  \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)| = 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle |x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)| = 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x^{k}(t)-y^{k}(t)= 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x^{(k)}(t)=y^{(k)}(t) \quad, for\ all\  k$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x(t)=y(t) \quad  (1)$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x=y $

If this is my proof is correct, why is true (1)? Please, someone to help me

Comment: (1) is false in general, assuming that you are talking about a single $t$.

Comment: But for what you want simply consider $k=0$, for all $t$.

Comment: I know this is not true when k is finite number. Could it be true because of the conditions infinitely differentiable functions

Comment: Why is it that $\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot  \frac{\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|}{1+\displaystyle \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)|  }    = 0 \quad,$ for all  $k$?

Comment: Yes, it is .a single t from [a,b].Thanks.

Comment: Therefore, the series converge then a general member equal zero

Comment: I apologize for my poor english

Comment: Is now this part of the proof correct?

Comment: $\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle  \max_{\substack{t \in [a,b]}}|x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)| = 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle |x^{(k)}(t)-y^{(k)}(t)| = 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$


$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x^{k}(t)-y^{k}(t)= 0 \quad, for\ all\  k$

especially, it is true for $k=0$, then is true

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x(t)-y(t)= 0 \quad, for\   k=0$

$\Longrightarrow$
$\displaystyle x=y $

Comment: Of course,  t is an arbitrary fixed from [a,b].

Comment: Yes, that is correct for arbitrary $t$.